# Python: Import Error: DLL load failed : pybind11 c++ extension

Tags: python, dllimport, pybind11

I am struggling to refresh the pyEDM (https://github.com/SugiharaLab/pyEDM) package for windows. The package uses pybind11 to wrap the cppEDM (C++ computation engine) which calls LAPACK directly from the C++ code. On Nix systems, no problem. In win I use mingw to build the Py Extension linking to a binary libopenblas.lib, which has worked in the past. This is built on Azure DevOps as I work in Linux.

With the latest libopenblas.lib the build succeeds. However, at load time I see:
`Import Error: DLL load failed while importing pyBindEDM: The specified module could not be found.`

I see in the wheel there is a pyBindEDM.cp39-win_amd64.pyd file, which I understand is the "dll" of the extension (Windows is a foreign land to me.) pyBindEDM is the name of the module derived via pybind11, vis:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE( pyBindEDM, pyMod ) {
    pyMod.doc() = "Python bindings to cppEDM via pybind11.";
    ...
}
```

Attempting to examine the .pyd load dependency with Dependency Walker on a Windows 10 machine, the program just spins endlessly with no feedback.

How does one approach unraveling the Import Error for a pybind11 wrapped c++ extension?

---

Update: Apologies if editing the original post is poor etiquette, I do not see an option to add an extension.

To reframe the issue:

As above, a pybind11 wrapper of a c++ library libEDM.a API to create the pyEDM package. libEDM.a calls LAPACK `dgelss` directly.

Previously, I linked with a static openblas.a using mingw to build the .pyd. No .dll needed at runtime. Now, if this is done with the latest libopenblas.a, the linker complains:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\a\1\s\cppEDM/lib\openblas.lib(memory.obj):(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to `__imp__cprintf'
```

I have not been able to resolve this. Static linking is the preferred approach.

A second approach is to build against a .dll (libopenblas.lib), which completes. However, when the pyEDM package is loaded in Python:

```
Import Error: DLL load failed while importing pyEDMBind: The specified module could not be found.
```

Using the Dependency application (thank you Mašek), and, if I place libopenblas.dll in the PATH, the unresolved .pyd dependency is python39.dll.

I would prefer not to try and bundle a .dll with the package, and unravel why python39.dll is not found, but in any case, have not been able to deliver a successful build that loads and runs.

Any and all directions are much appreciated. Please forgive my lack of post etiquette if I have transgressed norms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Dependency Walker on a Windows 10" -- if that's what I think it is, it doesn't work on Win10. Use https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies instead.

Comment: Thanks Dan. With the correct tool I see that python39.dll and libopenblas.dll are unresolved to load the .pyd. Not being a stackoverlow post adept, I would like to reframe the question. Perhaps best to close this one with comment and start a new question, or, reformulate this one to seek guidance on how to best resolve the issue of building a pybind11 extension linking to openblas?

Answer (score 0):

Although the issue is not resolved as the python extension still fails on Windows, there are two steps along the way which at least partially address the posed questions.

---

Issue 1: How does one approach unraveling the Import Error for a pybind11 wrapped c++ extension?

On Windows 10 the Dependencies application provides an answer: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Thank you Mašek.

---

Issue 2: Linking binary libopenblas.a against pybind11 C++ extension yields:
`` C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\a\1\s\cppEDM/lib\openblas.lib(memory.obj):(.text+0x44a): undefined reference to `__imp__cprintf' ``

It seems the binary libopenblas.a posted on https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/ are built with mingw 9.3, if the extension is built with mingw 9.5, the unresolved references are resolved.